# Прокрутка сразу трех строк в jQuery Slider Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Добрый день!

Как сделать, чтобы slider scrollbar прокручивал не одну строку с содержимым, а сразу три.
Slider стандартный [jquery simple scrollbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll). Планируется, что содержимое ("квадратики") определённого размера будут добавляться динамически. Причём этих квадратиков может быть хоть и 5 штук, а строчек должно быть строго три.
Есть идеи как это сделать? В jquery новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае неважно сколько "строчек" будет. Двигается контейнер, а сколько в нем будет строк или квадратиков зависит от вас. Важна только ширина контейнера.

вот тот же [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/GtJAk/) с измененной шириной контейнера... ваши три строки.

Comment: Изменения только в том, что к исходному примеру добавлены несколько строк до комментария. если у вас работает исходный пример с jqueryui, то просто добавьте эти строки в начало js-функции.
смысл в них в том, что они задают ширину и высоту контейнера по размерам квадратиков. этого можно добиться просто в css, например...

Comment: Дело в том что у меня ширина резиновая (100%), а необходимо именно три строчки. Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Правое нижнее поле, там где результат, - это frame. Просто откройте исходник этого фрейма.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался как скопировать. Ответьте пожалуйста на вопрос про ширину.

Comment: Ширина не может быть 100%, иначе скроллинга просто не будет, квадратики будут сами переноситься на следующие строки и их будет столько сколько влезет в строку при 100%.
В любом случае надо рассчитывать ширину контейнера относительно квадратиков.
В примере с jqueryui ширина контейнера заранее посчитана и вынесена в css 2440px. Если у вас квадратики добавляются динамически, значит и ширину эту надо менять динамически так, чтоб было 3 строки.
Плюс слайдер глючит при указании ширины в %.